# Element margin not working when is wrapped by table cell

Tags: html, css

I have links inside table cells. The table width will be fixed so if the  elements are longer than 4, the links will wrap but they look squeezed. I tried applying margins but it looks like is not making any effect. It seems that height:auto is not taking the margin into consideration?

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/czcz/w2b7h1Ly/)

```
 table tr td {
    width: 350px;
   border: 1px dotted #999999;
    height: auto;
}


.post-tag  {
    padding: 4px 10px 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.3;
    color: #FFF;
    background: #9fa6ad;
    transition: background .15s ease;
    margin:10px;
    }
 a.post-tag:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    background: #f69c55;
}

<table class="table table-striped">
<thead><tr><th></th><th>Left</th><th>Right</th></tr><th></th></thead>
<tbody>
  <tr><td>INK</td><td><a  class="post-tag" href="#">798798981 - a </a><a class="post-tag" href="#">154981 - a </a><a  class="post-tag" href="#">798798981 - a </a></td><td>INK</td><td><a class="post-tag" href="#">154981 - a </a><a  class="post-tag" href="#">798798981 - a </a></td><td></td></tr>


  <tr><td>INK</td><td><a class="post-tag" href="#">154981 - a </a><a  class="post-tag" href="#">798798981 - a </a><a class="post-tag" href="#">154981 - a </a><a  class="post-tag" href="#">798798981 - a </a></td><td>INK</td><td><a class="post-tag" href="#">154981 - a </a><a  class="post-tag" href="#">798798981 - a </a></td><td></td></tr>



</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Add `display:block` for the links ...

Comment: I had to refresh my JSfiddle. all is working good thanks!